# Background worker RunWorkCompleted Event

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have following wpf program, what i want to do is btnAnalyzer_click method to wait till both of the DoWork & RunWorkerCompleted methods finish. So i used a  AutoResetEvent, but now bwAnalyze_click method(#4 line) run after the DoWork and then WorkerCompleted method(line order - #1 #2 #4 & #3). But i want them to execute in the order #1 #2 #3 & #4. Any solutions or suggestions?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly BackgroundWorker bwAnalyzer = new BackgroundWorker();
    private AutoResetEvent autoReset;//to signal the end of the BackgroudnWork

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        autoReset = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        bwAnalyzer.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
        bwAnalyzer.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkerCompleted);
    }

    void WorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Completed"); #3
        autoReset.Set();
    }

    void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("load"); #2

    }

    private void btnAnalyze_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bwAnalyzer.RunWorkerAsync(); #1
        autoReset.WaitOne();//when commented working properly
        Console.WriteLine("click"); #4
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answers suggesting using Tasks will work, I'm a bit confused on why you want to wait until the background worker completes its work before you let the UI thread's click event continue. As far as I understand, you use a background worker because you want to perform background work without blocking the UI. The way you asked your question suggests that you want to block the UI until your work completes. In that case, why use a separate thread at all?

Also, regarding your comment:

```
autoReset.WaitOne();//when commented working properly
```

I'm assuming that if you leave it uncommented, the UI blocks permanently? When you call `autoReset.WaitOne()` in the button's click event, you're blocking the UI thread. While `DoWork` will run on a background thread, the `RunWorkerCompleted` event runs on the UI thread. So RunWorkerCompleted will never get to execute.

If you comment the `WaitOne()` call, I don't believe it'll work "properly" at all. I tested it, and it varies between click->load->completed and load->click->completed due to a race between the UI thread and the background thread.

Comment: yes, i understand your point, waiting and using background worker is useless. I'm editing existting code base, so removing background worker seems lots of work. So i tried to  change the order of click and complete while using background worker....

Comment: I see! Well the easiest way is to move everything after RunWorkerAsync to a new method, and call that in WorkerCompleted()... Then you're guaranteed to have it execute linearly without blocking anything. Though I must say I feel a bit iffy about code like that for maintenance's sake :)

Comment: @Rowbear: If you're editing existing code why not improve the design since you have the chance to? :) [`"Leave the campground cleaner than the way you found it."`](http://alvinalexander.com/programming/clean-code-quotes-robert-c-martin)

Comment: @RobinMaben: I completely agree. If it were me, I'd rip the whole background worker out.

Answer (score 1):

Use Tasks, and use the ContinueWith method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I guess the following should give the desired behaviour -

```
 private void btnAnalyze_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {      

       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {   

       })
       .ContinueWith(f => {            

       })
       .Wait(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here are rightly asking you to try and do what you want to do with TPL, but if you have a complex scenario where u need to use the ManualResetEvent/ AutoResetEvent then here is the solution to you problem. 
Just surround your btn click logic in a Task or a thread. The idea being that you dont want to hold the UI(STA Main) Thread. This is resulting in some runtime optimizations and resulting in undesired behavior.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                bwAnalyzer.RunWorkerAsync(); //#1
                autoReset.WaitOne(); //when commented working properly
                Console.WriteLine("click"); //#4
            });
```

Just having above snippet should give you desired behavior.